# Javascript Prototype Inheritance and Object.create()?

Tags: javascript, prototype

There is something confusing me about prototypes in JS.

Let's suppose I have an object like this :

```html
let a = {
  b: 1
};
```

Now, I want to create another object which inherits of the properties of 'a'.

```html
let obj = Object.create(a);
```

So in this situation, I will link the **proto** of my 'obj' to the **proto** of 'a' which will link to the Object.prototype. The first question is, does it remove the link of obj.**proto** to replace by the a.**proto** ?

Now let's suppose I do:

```html
a = 2;
```

I would think it updates 'a' in memory removing his references.

So now if I do :

```html
a.isPrototypeOf(obj)
```

It logically returns **false**. But weirdly 'obj' still point to the property b and can access it(obj.b print 1). What is the mecanism beyond that ?

Comment: b was copied into the prototype of obj, therefore you dont need a anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, when you replace an object with another one new value, the object's old reference will be cut off from the variable. But it will be still alive until the linked variable dies.

```
var x = { a:10 }
var y = { x };
x = 10;
```

Now, everyone would think that, y will carry the value 10 with the property `x`. But that's not, as i said above the x's older memory location will be stay alive until y garbage collected. At the same time, the x would get assigned with newer memory location for the newer value.

So in your case, you are just losing the reference of `a` by replacing some other value. Hence you cannot use `isPrototypeOf(obj)` anywhere after replacing the value of `a`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how can we remove the 'a' property ? if we use "delete y.a" in your example it will do nothing because 'a' is not a own property of y.

Comment: @musecz Obviously, It will not delete that. Since `y.a` will be undefined. We can delete it by `delete y.x.a`

Comment: When I try that I got "Cannot convert undefined or null to object" - I suppose because x is no more a real reference to y